# Как открыть новое консольное окно в c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++11

Суть примерно такова, дано два задания, при запуске .exe файла, нас показывают варианты заданий(элементарное меню) и просят ввести номер варианта.
 
 Вся проблема, в том что нужно что бы после выбора варианта, задание выполнялось в новом консольном окне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа не может одновременно работать в двух разных консолях. Если нужно новое консольное окно, значит запускайте отдельную консольную программу вызовом функции `system` или `ShellExecute`. Номер варианта передавайте в командной строке.

Если основная программа должна дожидаться окончания второй, а потом снова предлагать выбор, то лучше запускать вторую программу через `CreateProcess` и ждать ее завершения функцией `WaitForSingleObject`.